# Do not save PDF if a file with the same name already exists (Google App Script + Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Today the part of the script that defines how to save PDFs to a shared folder in Google Drive looks like this:

```
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();

    //...get token and Blob (do not create the file);

    var fileName = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Gerais").getRange("H2").getValue();

    //Access or create the 'Squads' folder;
    var folder; //declare folder;
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads"); //returns iterator;
    if(folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    }else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Squads");
    }

    //Remove duplicate file with the same name;
    var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName); //returns iterator;
    if(existing.hasNext()) {
      var duplicate = existing.next();

      var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
      var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
        method: 'delete',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
      });
      if(dres.getResponseCode()>=400) {
        //handle errors;
      }
    }

    //add file;
    folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);
```

As I share the folder with others, I can only edit the files owned by me.

I would like some help on the following problem...

1 - Analyze if there is a file with the name I am trying to save and try to delete it to save a new one over if I own the file. (Already exists in script)

2 - If the file is from someone else, he will not be able to delete it in the step above. (Already exists in script)

3 - If can not delete it, he will give up trying to save the file, because this way, never have a duplicate file with the same data in the folder. (Does not exist in script yet → My need)

**Problem: In the current format it tries to delete the existing file to create a new one over, being able to delete or not it, he saves the new file, sometimes resulting in two files from two different people in the same folder. This can not happen.**

**And I need it not to give an error message if it can't save, because there are more lines below it that need to keep running until the end of the script if it doesn't save the file because there is already one with the same name.**

I tried using the IF method, but it causes an error that makes the script stop, the base I tried to use was:

```
var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName); //returns iterator;
    if(existing.hasNext()) {
      var duplicate = existing.next();
           if(dres.getResponseCode()>=400) {
        //handle errors;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create new file only when the file could be deleted.
- You don't want to stop the script even when the file couldn't be deleted.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that the if statement of `if(existing.hasNext()) {}` is required to be modified.
- `muteHttpExceptions: true` is used for the request. So even if the status code is not 200, the script is not stopped.
- When you want to create new file only when the file could be deleted, how about adding `if (status == 200)`?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify he if statement of `if(existing.hasNext()) {}` of your script.

```
if(existing.hasNext()) {
  var duplicate = existing.next();

  var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
  var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
    method: 'delete',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
  });
  var status = dres.getResponseCode(); // Added
  if (status >=400) { // Modified
    //handle errors;
  } else if (status == 200) {
    folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName); // Added
  }
} else {
  folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName); // Added
}
```

- In this modification, please remove `folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);` at the last line of your script in your question.

#### Note:

- As other pattern, at first, if the owner of the file is checked, how about the following modified script?

  ```
  if(existing.hasNext()) {
    var duplicate = existing.next();
    if (duplicate.getOwner().getEmail() == Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) { // Added
      var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
      var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
        method: 'delete',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
      });
      var status = dres.getResponseCode(); // Added
      if (status >=400) { // Modified
        //handle errors;
      } else if (status == 200) {
        folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName); // Added
      }
    }
  } else {
    folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName); // Added
  }
  ```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I understand that the second option (indicated below **Note**), by first analyzing only the files that I own, will work more correctly than simple modification. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. Although both patterns can work, when at first, the owner of the file is checked, the process cost can be reduced, because when the owner of the file is not you, `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is not run. So I think that it's yes for your replying.

Comment: Always very attentive and with accurate words in your answers. Thank you again!

Comment: Tanaike ... I was wrong about one detail. In fact when a file with the same name does not exist, it should also save. I just did a test, when there is no file with the name I will use, it does not save. I'm sorry could you help me?

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, please tell me. In this case, you can also declare `folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName)` as a function.

Comment: Confirmed script execution. Everything went perfectly well. Thanks mate!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong please: By activating the script when there was a file created by me with the same name, it was deleting the old file but not creating a new one. I made a change in → ```} else if (status == 200) {``` to → ```} else if (status = 200) {``` and from that change he started to delete the old one and save the new one, is that correct or did I modify something that worked but is not the way it should be? In the case there were ```==``` and I changed to ```=``` and so it worked

Comment: @Frederico Mattos `if (status = 200)` is the same that `200` is substituted to `status`. And the script of the statement is always run. In your case, you can also modify to `if (status >=400) { //handle errors; } folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);`.

Comment: @ Tanaike I figured out what I needed to adjust ... In ```GAS``` actually instead of ```200``` the value needs to be ```204``` ... Getting then → ```(status == 204)```

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for the additional information.